# How to manipulate bits in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation

Let's say I have a variable `X = 4`

How to create a number with a binary representation `1111` (ones with length `X`) using bitwise operators ( `& | ~ << ^` ) and take a position and toggle the bit at that position to `zero (0)`.

Example:

```
X = initial(4) // X should be : 1111
Y = solution(X, 2) // Y should be 1101
Z = solution(Y, 3) // Z should be 1001
```

Comment: You can set a given bit `i` to `0` with `x & (~(1<<i))`.

Comment: ok, how to go from number 4 to 1111 ?

Comment: @BadisMerabet: `(1<<(n+1))-1`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem That's one `1` too much: `console.log(((1<<(4+1))-1).toString(2)) // "11111"`

Comment: @Andreas: argh, yes, `(1<<4)-1`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you'd use [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) (or on modern browsers, the [exponentiation operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Exponentiation_(**)), `**`) and the [bitwise operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators) to do that.

```js
function initial(digits) {
  return Math.pow(2, digits) - 1;
}
function solution(value, bit) {
  return value & ~(1 << (bit - 1)); // () around `bit - 1` aren't necessary,
                                    // but I find it clearer
}
var X = initial(4);     // X should be : 1111
console.log(X.toString(2));
var Y = solution(X, 2); // Y should be 1101
console.log(Y.toString(2));
var Z = solution(Y, 3); // Z should be 1001
console.log(Z.toString(2));
```

Or — doh! — comments on the question point out that you can create the initial number without `Math.pow` or exponentiation:

```js
function initial(digits) {
  return (1 << digits) - 1;
}
function solution(value, bit) {
  return value & ~(1 << (bit - 1)); // () around `bit - 1` aren't necessary,
                                    // but I find it clearer
}
var X = initial(4);     // X should be : 1111
console.log(X.toString(2));
var Y = solution(X, 2); // Y should be 1101
console.log(Y.toString(2));
var Z = solution(Y, 3); // Z should be 1001
console.log(Z.toString(2));
```

Comment: Yes, I like the second solution. more down to earth.

Comment: @BadisMerabet - Yeah, I wasn't thinking "bits" enough, but fortunately Willem Van Onsem was.